How to Resolve "FLOOD_PREMIUM_WAIT_3" Error During Large File Upload
I'm encountering the following error when attempting to upload a 2 GB video.

telethon.errors.rpcbaseerrors.FloodError: RPCError 420:
FLOOD_PREMIUM_WAIT_3 (caused by SaveBigFilePartRequest)

Is there any way to resolve this issue, or do I need to wait for the next Telethon update?
Code:
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

async def upload_file_with_retry(client, file_path, part_size_kb=512):
    """Uploads a file in parts with FloodWaitError handling."""
    part_size = part_size_kb * 1024
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    parts_count = (file_size + part_size - 1) // part_size

    logging.info(f"Starting file upload: {file_path}, size: {file_size} bytes, parts: {parts_count}")

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        uploaded_file = None
        for part_num in range(parts_count):
            logging.info(f"Uploading part {part_num + 1} of {parts_count}")
            part_start = part_num * part_size
            f.seek(part_start)
            part_data = f.read(part_size)

            wait_time = 5
            while True:
                try:
                    uploaded_file = await client.upload_file(
                        bytes(part_data),  
                        file_name=os.path.basename(file_path),
                        file_size=file_size  
                    )
                    logging.info(f"Part {part_num + 1} successfully uploaded")
                    break
                except FloodWaitError as e:
                    logging.warning(
                        f"Flood error during upload! File: {file_path}, part {part_num + 1}, waiting {wait_time} seconds, error: {e}")
                    await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)
                    wait_time *= 2
        return uploaded_file

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash) as client:
        caption = "caption"

        media_group = [
            types.InputMediaUploadedDocument(
                file=await upload_file_with_retry(client, "video.mp4"),
                thumb=await upload_file_with_retry(client, "image.jpg"),
                mime_type='video/mp4', 
                attributes=[
                    types.DocumentAttributeVideo(
                        duration=2940,
                        w=1920,
                        h=1080,
                        supports_streaming=True
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]

        for i in range(2, 11):
            video_file = f"video{i}.mp4"
            image_file = f"image{i}.jpg"
            if os.path.exists(video_file) and os.path.exists(image_file):
                media_group.append(
                    types.InputMediaUploadedDocument(
                        file=await upload_file_with_retry(client, video_file),
                        thumb=await upload_file_with_retry(client, image_file),
                        mime_type='video/mp4',
                        attributes=[
                            types.DocumentAttributeVideo(
                                duration=2940,
                                w=1920,
                                h=1080,
                                supports_streaming=True
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                )
            else:
                print(f"File not found: {video_file}")

        try:
            await client.send_file(
                " ",
                media_group,
                caption=caption 
            )
        except FloodWaitError as e:
            print(f"Flood error during sending! Waiting for {e.seconds} seconds...")
            await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)

asyncio.run(main())

I tried changing the chunk size, but it didn't help. I'm new to programming.

I have the same problem but downloading a lot of files. It seems like telegram detect you are making a lot of request and they limit you. In my case i only can exec my program one time each week.
